# Unable to connect QNAP NAS ldap to Domino server

Tags: ldap, ibm-domino, qnap

We've just bought a QNAP 419 NAS to the office and for simplicity I'd like to authenticate using LDAP from our Domino server.

qnap ldap auth demands the following settings:

- Base DN
- Root DN
- password
- User
- base DN
- Group base DN

Our Domino server has the hierarchy: `O=/`

I can't figure out what to put in the above fields except root DN and password.

We have a firewall (Fortigate) with ldap authentication to our Domino server that's is working fine. Here we specify the DN as `O=` but it does not specify what DN…

I have search for others using this combo but no hits.

Domino server: 8.5.3 QNAP: TS419P II, fw: 3.8.1 Build 20121205

Comment: I have talked to the folks at qnap and they haven't replied with a solution, unfortunatly.
*stuck*

Answer (score 0):

According to QNAP support:

QNAP can support the LDAP server if it provide at least following object classes and attributes.

- objectclass posixAccount
- objectclass shadowAccount
- objectclass posixGroup
- attribute uid
- attribute uidNumber
- attribute gidNumber
- attribute cn
- attribute homeDirectory
- attribute loginShell
- attribute uniqueMember
- attribute gecos